# oracle row count into shell script variable

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I want to get count of oracle table into shell variable so I can compare to row count in csv file and make sure record counts match. When I execute below script I get: COUNT(*) ---------- 100000
I would like to just get: 100000

What are good approaches?

```
VAR="$(sqlplus -S usr/pw@//host:1521/db <<ENDOFSQL
select count(*) from table;
exit;
ENDOFSQL)"  
echo $VAR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
VAR="$(sqlplus -S usr/pw@//host:1521/db <<ENDOFSQL
set head off
select count(*) from table;
exit;
ENDOFSQL)"  
echo $VAR
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! Tried to vote this up, but don't have enough reputation points :(

Comment: @user1048488 : hover/click on the number between the up and down arrow at the top left of this answer to "accept" the answer. You'll see a green check-mark appear. Then Shankar will get 15 points reputation. Good luck to all.